# Google Custom Search problem: Request throttled due to daily limit being reached

Tags: search, google-custom-search

We often receive reports regarding Google Custom Search (Custom Search JSON API) not functioning on our website: https://pomoc.home.pl/

We have noticed the answer we receive from the server, when the search engine stops working:

```
// API callback
hndlr({
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "Request throttled due to daily limit being reached.",
"errors": [

{ "message": "Request throttled due to daily limit being reached.", "domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "dailyLimitExceeded" }
],
"status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"
}
}
);
```

It appears that we have reached the daily query limit (which is 10,000). The odd thing is, that when this happens we should no longer have access to the search engine, but instead it just starts working again after some time; these are very temporary lock-ups.

1. Is there any way for me to verify the number of queries/requests via https://console.developers.google.com/ ? If so, please kindly let me know where exactly.
2. According to Google Analytics, the daily number of unique queries does not exceed 1,000/day. This is why I am inclined to believe that we do not exceed the daily 10,000 limit, but I may be wrong.
3. Do you have any suggestions as to what may be the issue with the Google Custom Search failing for us (if it is, in fact, not the daily query limit)? If we do, however, somehow exceed the limit, is there any way to optimize the engine (e.g. adding captcha, so that various bots would not generate additional queries?).

Answer (score 1):

You can view your quota information at https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?service=customsearch.googleapis.com&project=YOUR_PROJECT_ID

You may be hitting the "Queries per 100 seconds per user" quota. You can use the quotaUser parameter described here https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/7035610 to identify individual users.